# Did the Gamemakers help Katniss when she was in the tree?

Tags: the-hunger-games

There's a moment in the film when Katniss

> is under siege while resting on top of a tree.

She manages to get out of this situation by

> dropping a *Tracker Jacker* nest on the tributes beneath her.

I would expect it to be quite noisy, or at least noisy enough to be heard during night. Was it there the whole time? Or did the Gamemakers help her out by placing it there?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I haven't seen the film, so this is from the book.

The bees (called Tracker Jackers) had been subdued by the smoke from the earlier fire, so weren't particularly active or noisy. Katniss herself hadn't noticed them because of this fact, but has her attention drawn to it by Rue from a neighbouring tree.

It's only in the morning, when the effects of the smoke have worn off, that they start to become more active and aggressive, and this is when Katniss uses it as a weapon.

I would guess that they're simply one of the many dangers present in the arena, and Katniss was fortunate enough to find herself stuck in a tree with a nest full of subdued bees. Given that the Gamemakers really have no interest in a particular tribute winning, I can't see why they would have helped her out of that situation.

Comment: And the implications are that TJ nests are quiet enough if they are not being disturbed. When they are thrown out of their tree onto a group of people, they would be very annoyed, and so very noisy.

Comment: The film is pretty much the same, although without Katniss's internal dialogue giving the reader the reasons why she didn't notice the TJ nest before Rue pointed it out.

Comment: Seems like a good example of "Deus ex machina" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina

Comment: Also, in the book, Katniss does most of the sawing through the tree limb while the anthem is playing to mask the noise.

Comment: @WilliamJackson That seems more to mask the noise from the Careers on the ground below her than to avoid aggravating the tracker jackers, though: "And will the vibration from the sawing raise the swarm? And what if the Careers figure out what I'm doing and move their camp? That would defeat the whole purpose. I realize that the best chance I'll have to do the sawing without drawing notice will be during the anthem." *The Hunger Games*, Chapter 14.

Answer (score 6):

No they didn't

> From the books, the wasps (aka Tracker Jackers) were a genetically modified muttation already present in the arena.

Comment: They may already be present in the arena, but it is steel possible they were planted exactly above Katniss by Gamemakers.